# What settings do I need to get the outmatched achievements on Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2, achievements

This is not a tactics question.

I choose the "Versus A.I." option from the main screen and then a custom on Megaton vs 2 Medium A.I. However, after beating them, I don't get the achievement.

What are the correct settings I need to get these outmatched achievements? Do they need to be played on particular maps or something like that?

Comment: Are you playing online? You have to be connected to BattleNet to get achievements

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You must play this as "Multiplayer - Custom game" otherwise you wont get the achievement. So selecting "Single Player - Versus AI" is actually a waste of time when you want achievements i think. I always create a custom game in MP and have no trouble getting achievements. As for the map/game settings, "melee" works for me. Good luck!

Comment: this is annoying in that Blizzard doesn't make it at all obvious that this is necessary.

Comment: @PeterRecore Blizzard does say "custom game" in the achievement text

Comment: Does it say "multiplayer"?  that's what i would consider obvious.  I don't have SC2 with me right now so i can't actually check.

Comment: @McKay You can play a "custom game" in single player. Thus it is very confusing.